# questions on convergence for discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

I would like if someone can go over on my solution on a question having to do with  convergence in the discrete topology.  Also, I have some related questions for further clarifications after.

First some definitions:

**Definition 1:** We say that $y$ *converges to* $x$, in symbols, $y_n\rightarrow x$, if for every neighborhood $N$ of $x$, $y_n\in N$ *eventually*.  That is there exists  $n_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $n\geq n_0$ implies $y_n \in N$ Any point $x$ such that $y_n\rightarrow x$ is called a *limit* of $\{y_n\}$.

**Definition 2:** A *constant sequence* is a sequence whose range consists of a single number, that is $s_n = c$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Definition 3:** A sequence is *eventually constant* if there is a number $c$ and an integer $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $s_n = c$.

**Question:**  $y_n\rightarrow x$ in the discrete topology if and only if $y_n=x$ eventually.

I am not sure if my solution to the ($\Leftarrow$) direction is expressed correctly.  Here it is:

Let $T=(S, \tau)$ be a discrete topological space with set $S$, $\tau = \mathcal{P}(S)$, $\tau := \{X: X\subset S, X \text{ is an open set}\}$.  $y_n=x$ eventually, let $\{x\}$ be an open neighborhood of $x\in S$, and from Definition 1, there exists a $n_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$  $y_n\in \{x\}$ which implies $y_n\rightarrow x$.

I am not sure if my solution means i have shown that the sequence ${y_n}$ converges to $x$ in the discrete topology.  Also, I have read in various places online with the discrete topology, the only sequences that can converge are either eventually constant sequences or constant sequences.  I don't understand why that is?  Does that mean we can't have other sequences, such as ones that are decreasing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @MPW thank you for the edit.  :)

Comment: Note I wasn't sure what you meant in the last paragraph so I left it. Can you correct it?

Comment: @MPW i corrected.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I was actually referring to the part that says "$y_n$ converges to in the discrete topology" because it doesn't make sense. Converges to what? I corrected the formatting but left the text. You should edit that to clarify.

Comment: @MPW fixed it.  Thank you for pointing it out.  Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

If $y_n = x$ eventually, then $(y_n) \to x$ in **any** space: Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ and let $N$ be the promised index such that $$\forall n \ge N: y_n = x\tag{1}$$

But then (as $x \in U$):

$$\forall n \ge N: y_n \in U\tag{2}$$ and as $U$ was an arbitrary neighbourhood of $x$, $(y_n) \to x$ by definition.

The reverse: if $X$ is discrete and $(y_n) \to x$, then $y_n = x$ eventually:

As $X$ is discrete, we know that all sets are open, and in particular $U=\{x\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$. By the definition of the *convergence* $(y_n) \to x$ applied to this $U$, we have $(2)$ as above for some index $N$. But $y_n \in U=\{x\}$ iff $y_n =x$ so $(1)$ holds and indeed $y_n =x$ eventually.

Comment: Thank you for the clear solution.  I want to ask that the notion of a sequence being $\textit{eventually}$ in a set, it means beyond the $n$-term onwards will be in every neighborhood which contains $x$.  Another way to say it is that all the neighborhood which contain $x$ contain the m-tail of the sequence.   But $x$ is one of the terms of that $m$-tail, and not necessarily the first term in the $m$-tail sequence.  Thanks.

Comment: @SethMai a sequence is eventually in a set, if there is an index $N$ such that for all terms with index $ n \ge N$, the term $y_n$ is in that set. So the set contains a tail of the sequence. A sequence converges to $x$ iff every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a tail of the sequence. This definition also applies to so-called *nets*, which are generalisations of sequences. But what exactly is your question about the notion “being eventually in a set”? We indeed do not care about the first terms of a sequence; what matters are the tails.

Comment: if a sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges to $x$, then every neighborhood $N$ contains the tail of the sequence $\{y_m, y_{m+1}, y_{m+1}, ....\}$.  $x$, the value that $\{y_n\}$ converges to doesn't necessarily have to be $x=y_m$.

Comment: @SethMai no, but in the *discrete* topology we can take the special neighbourhood $\{ x\}$ ( all neighbourhoods contain a tail so this one too) and then all $y_n$ must be $x$ to be in that neighbourhood. Is that unclear? Seems obvious to me.

Comment: yes, thank you.  That is clear to me.  I got was looking at the exercises from Albert Wilansky's text Topology for Analysis, hence where i got the questions from.  I think many topology text just gloss over the "eventually" terminonlogy relating to convergenve and instead concentrates more on the distinction between box and product topology when it comes to convergenve.  Not sure why though. I hope the two different perspectives are equivalent.